# Subscriber and publisher in the same node not working with costum msg

Tags: ros, nodehandle, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know that this question might be asked before, but I did not find the final solution for it.
Here is the question:

I want to write a node that subscribe for data from a topic then publish these data to another topic. So, mainly I want a publisher and subscriber in the same node.
So What I did so far is the following:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include "pctx_control/Control.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "pctx_control/pctx.h" 
#include <sstream>


pctx_control::Control controlmsg ;

void function_callback (const geometry_msgs::Twist &msg) 
 {

controlmsg.ch = 0 ;
controlmsg.values[0] = msg.linear.x;
controlmsg.values[1] = msg.linear.y;
controlmsg.values[2] = msg.linear.z;
std::cout << "d1"<<controlmsg.values[0] << std::endl ;
std::cout << "d2" <<controlmsg.values[1]<< std::endl ;
std::cout << "d3" <<controlmsg.values[2]<< std::endl ;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
 ros::Publisher pub = n.advertise<pctx_control::Control>("topic2", 100);

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topic1", 1000, function_callback);

 ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
 ros::spinOnce();

 int count = 0;
 while (ros::ok())
  {
 
    pub.publish(controlmsg);

  ros::spin();
  loop_rate.sleep();
   
 }

return 0;
 }
```

I want to save data that I want to publish in a "custom msg" pctx_control::Control type;

This msg has the following format:

```
int32 ch
int32 value
int16[] values
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195306/subscriber-and-publisher-in-the-same-node-not-working-with-costum-msg/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you make the publisher global, you can publish as soon as the message is received in function_callback(). Then the while() loop can be replaced with just ros::spin();

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include "pctx_control/Control.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "pctx_control/pctx.h" 
#include <sstream>

ros::Publisher pub;
pctx_control::Control controlmsg;

void function_callback (const geometry_msgs::Twist &msg) 
{
  controlmsg.ch = 0;
  controlmsg.values.resize(3);
  controlmsg.values[0] = msg.linear.x;
  controlmsg.values[1] = msg.linear.y;
  controlmsg.values[2] = msg.linear.z;
  pub.publish(controlmsg);
  std::cout << "d1" << controlmsg.values[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d2" << controlmsg.values[1] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "d3" << controlmsg.values[2] << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "my_node");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  
  pub = n.advertise<pctx_control::Control>("topic2", 100);

  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("topic1", 1000, function_callback);

  // Handle ROS callbacks until shutdown
  ros::spin();
  
  return 0;
}
```

Edit: Changed vector indexing to push_back()
Edit: Changed vector indexing back to brackets, and reinitialize with resize() every iteration per comment from @dornhege

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2014-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-20**:
@kmhallen
I did what you said, I got an error said Segmentation fault (core dumped) .

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-20**:
I was tracing the problem it give me this error after this line of code

```
controlmsg.values[0] = msg.linear.x;
```

I maigh be filling this one in the wrong way.. what should I do ?? can you check the message type, please.

**Comment by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on 2014-10-20**:
I knew how to fill it using push_pack()..
Thanks for your help

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-20**:
Careful, this code is buggy. You must clear the values in the controlmsg every time before publishing or mvoe that to a local variable.